# Multiprocessing in C POSIX

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, posix, semaphore

I have two processes that need to communicate with each other. One is the sender and the other is the receiver.
The receiver should read a word from the user and save it in the shared memory. The sender should then read this word and use it to save an answer to it in the shared memory. Now the receiver should output this answer.

Small minimal example:

```
//Process 1
//
do
{
  strcpy(shared_mem->message, getCommand());
  sem_post(&semaphore_getMessage);
  sem_wait(&semaphore_getAnswer);
  printf("%s",shared_mem->Answer);
  } while (getCommand()!=0);





//Process 2
//

sem_wait(&semaphore_getMessage);
do
{  
  strcpy(shared_mem->Answer, getAnswer(shared_mem->Message));
  sem_post(&semaphore_getAnswer);
  sem_wait(&semaphore_getMessage);
} while (strcmp(shared_mem->Message, "Exit\n") != 0);
```

Unfortunately, I sometimes get a deadlock (i.e. my programme is permanently stuck in a state). I just don't know how... Does anyone have an idea? Language is C

The Semaphores are defined in an struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  sem_t semaphore_getMessage;
  sem_t semaphore_getAnswer;
} semaphores;
```

as are the filedescriptors and the mapping of the memory:

```
typedef struct
{
  sempahores *mapped_region_locks;
} mappings;


typedef struct
{
  int locks;
} filedescriptor;
```

The locks are then mapped to shared space:

```
filedescriptor->locks = shm_open(NAME_SEMAPHORES, FLAGS_READWRITE_ACCES, MODE_RW);

ftruncate(filedescriptor->locks, sizeof(filedescriptor)); 

mappings->mapped_region_locks = mmap(NULL, sizeof(semaphores), 
                      PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, filedescriptor->locks, 0); 

sem_init(&mapped_region_locks->semaphore_getMessage, 0, 1);
//in the first code snippet "mapped_region_locks->semaphore_getMessage" is referred to as "semaphore_getMessage" as it is easier to read.
```

Comment: Since you call `getCommand()` twice in the loop in process 1, it looks like you're only sending every other message.  Should not deadlock unless something else is using the semaphores, though.

Comment: Yeah sorry, this was a mistake. In the real Programme getCommand() is called in the beginning of the loop and the input is then assigned to a local buffer variable so that should not be an issue.

As for the deadlock: these are the only semaphores I use.

Comment: Well, your problem is likely in your actual program, not in the fragments you show here.  That's why questions like this require a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Well the thing is, that it works pretty fine without the locks (perhaps in 1 out of 50 runs, there would be a race condition) so I am pretty sure that the mistake lies somewhere in between these code lines. Perhaps I did the initalizing of the semaphores wrong. I added it to the question :)

Comment: If these are *processes* rather than *threads*, you need to call `sem_init` with a non-zero `pshared` value as its second argument -- see the man page for `sem_init`.  That's probably the cause of your deadlock.

Comment: Thanks this was the Problem! Thanks for your help :) Im pretty new to this site, how can I upvote your answer?